# Add user ID to woocommerce customer dashboard

Tags: php

Is there anyway I can add the user ID to the woocommerce customer dashboard?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce doesn't provide any such hook to display User ID on the dashbaord.

But you can add it by overwriting dashboard template into your theme file. You can view in brief of how to overwrite templates from below WooCommerce reference link.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

You need to copy template **dashboard.php** file from WooCommerce plugin template to **woocommerce/myaccount/** folder in your theme.

You can use a code to display **User ID** anywhere on the dashboard page.

```
<?php echo esc_html( $current_user->ID ); ?>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! thanks!
Is also possible to add this number to the woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php email?

Answer (score 1):

As with most mature plugins, Woocommerce offers a number of hooks to easily customize content such as the customer dashboard. With the proper hook, you should be able to quickly accomplish your goal.

Your best bet is reviewing the Woocommerce documentation at this [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

As for WordPress you can get the current user with the [get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) function.

Comment: No, no user_id hook. I know how to edit code, very little. I'm looking for something like 
<?php printf( __( 'Your user ID is: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . $user_id . '</strong>' ); ?>
But the correct code to add it to the dash board.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

To display name on Customer New Account email, try adding below code in **customer-new-account.php** email template file. Let me know if this works.

```
<?php $user = get_user_by( 'user_login', $user_login );
if($user){
    echo $user->ID;
}?>
```

Comment: no, it didnt work, email doesnt display any other information rather than regular information and my "mark" (a mark to check its using my email template). Maybe is not possible?